# Xamarin Forms navigating to a MasterDetail Page after a Content Page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an app using Xamarin Forms where when a user launches an app for the first time, they are sent to a login page.  Once they log in, they're redirected to the MasterPage, which is a MasterDetail Page.  However, when I try to navigate to the new MasterDetail Page, I only get the Detail Page, and the button to show the Master Portion is missing.  The only thing appearing on the app bar is the title I set.  I'm currently going to the MasterPage like this:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MasterPage())
{
     Title = "Welcome " + user.firstName
};
```

Every other run, this isn't an issue, since when a user opens the app it automatically logs them in and goes right to the MasterPage, except during their first use. However, this is a very important issue for me since it happens the first time a user uses my app and it will be part of their first impression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use a `MasterDetailpage`, you should not wrap it into a `Navigationpage` (like your code-example). Because the `MasterDetailPage` should everytime be on top and not inside a `NavigationPage`.

To navigate between different pages you should wrap your `DetailPage` from the `MasterDetailPage` inside a `NavigationPage`.

Here some code for clarification:

```
var view = new MyFirstPage();
Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterPage(view);
```

And inside the MasterPage constructor, do the following:

```
public MasterPage(Page detailpage)
{
    // Set the master-part
    Master = new MasterContentPage();

    // Set detail-part (with a navigation page)
    Detail = new NavigationPage(detailpage);
}
```

And after that, you can navigate inside your app with this navigation:

```
var mdp = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
await mdp.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(myNextPage);
```

I usually create a static helper class `AppNavigator` to do this stuff.

For further information, look at the [MasterDetailPage instructions on the Xamarin developer guides](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/).

Comment: This works but now on Android my MasterPage goes all the way to the top of my screen and onto the notification bar.  Do you know how to prevent that?

Comment: What do you mean with "goes all the way to the top of my screen"?

Comment: The master page itself takes up the entire height of the screen including into the notification bar.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand something.. but thats how the MasterPage works. When the user opens it, it slides in from the left side and fills up the entire height (but not the entire width). When you think, something is wrong, you might edit your question and add an image of the problem...